# Converting Python socket code to Java socket code

Tags: java, python, sockets, io

Given this python script:

```
import socket
import sys
import time

buf0 = "03".decode('hex')
buf1 = "0300".decode('hex')
buf2 = "8028".decode('hex')
package = buf0 + buf1 + buf2
HOST = "192.168.0.2"
PORT = 22
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.settimeout(3)
s.connect((HOST,PORT))
s.send(package)
rec = s.recv(1024)
s.close()
```

I need to do exactly the same with Java, right now I'm using this function to convert hexstring to ascii string:

```
public static String convertHexToString(String hex) {

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < hex.length() - 1; i += 2) {

    // grab the hex in pairs
    String output = hex.substring(i, (i + 2));
    // convert hex to decimal
    int decimal = Integer.parseInt(output, 16);
    // convert the decimal to character
    sb.append((char) decimal);

    temp.append(decimal);
}

return sb.toString();
}
```

I've done some experiments using Java sockets but with no success - the application that is supposed to receive the packet accepts the connection but does nothing while receiving the packet, so I suppose I've done something wrong.

With the python script everything works fine. I'm probably failing on something stupid. Any ideas?

Here is the java code:

```
String buff0 = "03";
String buff1 = "0300";
String buff2 = "8028";
String pack = convertHexToString(buff0) + convertHexToString(buff1) + convertHexToString(buff2);

Socket socket = null;
String host = "192.168.0.2";

try {
    socket = new Socket(Inet4Address.getByName(host), 22);
    System.out.println("connected");
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

BufferedReader in = null;
PrintStream out = null;

try {
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    out = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
    out.print(pack);
    System.out.println("sent");

    in.read();
    System.out.println("received");

    out.close();
    in.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I've rewrited it many times but always with no good result.

Comment: Please include your Java socket code in your question.

Comment: It looks like you have two client sockets.  With socket programming one side needs to be a "server" which binds to a port, and listens for and accepts incoming connections while the other side is a "client" which just connects to a host.  You will have to add a server socket to either your Java code or your python code or both.

Comment: @Pace nope, I send packets to a proprietary software that is listening for connections, I only need to develop the client side, right now the python one works fine.
I just need help to translate it in Java.

Comment: How certain are you that you are sending the correct thing out (or anything at all)?  A PrintStream's print method is going to encode the string based on the default platform encoding which might not be ASCII compatible.

Comment: @Pace I'm not certain about the validity of the content that's why I'm asking help, the python script works fine but I can't manage to do the same with the Java one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem sending an array of byte:

```
    String buff0 = "03";
    String buff1 = "0300";
    String buff2 = "8028";

    String packet = buff0 + buff1 + buff2;

    byte[] b = new BigInteger(packet,16).toByteArray();



    try {
        Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.0.2", 22);
        OutputStream socketOutputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
        socketOutputStream.write(b);
        InputStream socketInput = socket.getInputStream();
        System.out.println(socketInput.read());
        socket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

So i basically get the hex string, convert it to a byte array and send it using an OutputStream.